# How to Normalize a vector to gravity with accelerometer data

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

I have this data from an accelerometer.  Units are $\frac{m}{s^2}$.  The last column computes the magnitude

(sqrt of sum of squares: $\sqrt{\sum(v_i^2)}$)

```
timestamp   X   Y   Z   Magnitude
1423569932.50549    -6.606739999999999  0.53642 6.81562 9.50734
1423569932.52549    -6.8038300000000005 0.6149  6.739139999999999   9.596160000000001
1423569932.54549    -5.5437 1.94366 7.58447 9.59347
1423569932.56549    -6.9608300000000005 0.22351999999999997 7.04604 9.907060000000001
1423569932.58549    -7.4334 0.14520999999999998 6.4704  9.8561
```

From the magnitude above, you can see that gravity is still present (e.g., `9.80665`).  For a given observation, I want to subtract gravity from the magnitude and update the x,y,z acceleration readings based on some vector norm approach.  I do not know the orientation of the acceleration readings.

As you can see, the gravity subtraction will create a negative magnitude at times.  Maybe in this scenario do a norm up to "10" then implement the subtraction approach?

Here is my unit-norm function

```
vectorMagnitude = function(v)
{

  sqrt(sum(v^2));
}

unitVector = function(v)
{

  vlen = vectorMagnitude(v);  # can this be nonzero?
  v/vlen;
}
```

Following vector algebra, can I add or subtract to the magnitude and update the x,y,z to maintain the vector basis?

Comment: How can you do this without knowing what the orientation is?

Comment: This may help [How to remove gravity component from accelerometer X, Y readings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316178/how-to-remove-gravity-component-from-accelerometer-x-y-readings).

Comment: @AlexVong your link does indeed set the context of the problem.  In 3D, we have ax, ay, az (from a known origin), see [ax, ay, az](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108850-what-would-the-angles-be-for-a-3d-vector).  In this problem, gravity "orientation" is unknown.  However, we know the magnitude of gravity is constant, being eaten up by x,y,z in some arbitrary (unknown way) since we don't know the angle of gravity.  Can I not subtract gravity from known magnitude to create m', and solve for x',y',z'?  I have 4 variables and 4 unknowns, nonlinear.

Comment: Subtract g seems to be reasonable [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319564/how-to-account-for-acceleration-due-to-gravity-when-reading-from-accelerometer?rq=1)